# How can I determine that files need to be opened with IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I use IntelliJ 14.0.2 Ultimate on a Mac. When I first opened a specific file I determined that this file (and all others of that type) need to be opened with an external editor. For example, I specified that .md files need to be opened with TextWrangler.

How can I change it back to IntelliJ again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Setting (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>) | Editor | File Types
2. In "Recognized File Types" pane (at the top), find the `Files Opened in Associated Applications` entry and select it
3. In the "Registered Patterns" pane, find the *.md (and/or *.mkd, *.markdown, etc.) entry. Select it and remove it via the delete button [image] on the right
4. Click OK to close the settings dialog

You can then register the extension as plain text, or install the third-party Markdown plug-in ([IDEA Plug-In Repository Page](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5970?pr=idea), [Project's GitHub Page](https://github.com/nicoulaj/idea-markdown)). The Plug-in will auto-register markdown file extensions to open and be handled by the plug-in.